# Rails Gem access model columns_hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to update https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings/pull/84/files so that it can optionally utilize a json/jsonb column type (which would allow better querying)

everything just works when i comment out `serialize :value, Hash` because rails/postgres are handling the serialization.

I'm trying to add config to this Gem by using the `columns_hash` object to see the column types.

```
class Settings
  #... more
  if self.columns_hash['value'].type.to_sym == :text
    serialize :value, Hash
  end
end
```

On server start I am getting an error for missing a connection

```
There was an error while trying to load the gem 'my-rails-settings'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: No connection pool for MyRailsSettings
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/Users/blairanderson/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:570:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/blairanderson/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
```

[full stack trace](https://gist.github.com/blairanderson/d6e2759469d8148e4210ae5524904fc3)

Which kinda makes sense because its basically making a DB request on server start... are there other ways to achieve this same function without asking the user to set the config?

Comment: I suspect there might be more to that backtrace than a few lines. Could you please share the remainder? I think that this could be caused by having `Settings` being referred to in your application before Active Record is initialized.

Comment: Can you require your gem after rails has been loaded?

Comment: @RyanBigg https://gist.github.com/blairanderson/d6e2759469d8148e4210ae5524904fc3